# How do I correctly timing out an observable?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, system.reactive

Using an observable from event, I download the latest weather from a web service. I tested this out on the phone and emulator at home and it works fine. I brought the project with me to work and ran it using the emulator there. Now i'm not sure it its a firewall or what but it doesn't seem to get the weather, it just sits there forever, trying. So it got me thinking that if this was ever to happen on a phone then I need some kind of timeout in that if it can't get the weather in say 10 - 15 seconds then just give up.

Here is the example code so far

```
IObservable<IEvent<MyWeather.GetWeatherCompletedEventArgs>> observable =
          Observable.FromEvent<MyWeather.GetWeatherCompletedEventArgs>(Global.WeatherService, "MyWeather.GetWeatherCompleted").Take(1);

        observable.Subscribe(w =>
        {

            if (w.EventArgs.Error == null)
            {
               // Do something with the weather
            }
        });

        Global.WeatherService.GetWeatherAsync(location);
```

How can I get this to time out safely after a given time if nothing is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `FromEventPattern` (not `FromEvent`) so I've changed your observable to:

```
var observable =
      Observable
        .FromEventPattern<MyWeather.GetWeatherCompletedEventArgs>(
            Global.WeatherService, 
            "MyWeather.GetWeatherCompleted")
        .Take(1);
```

You could then do this:

```
var timeout =
    Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
        .Select(_ => (EventPattern<MyWeather.GetWeatherCompletedEventArgs>)null);

observable
    .Amb(timeout)
    .Subscribe(w =>
    {
        if (w != null && w.EventArgs.Error == null)
        {
           // Do something with the weather
        }
    });
```

Comment: Observable.FromEventPattern doesn't seem to be an option only .FromAsyncPattern,.FromAsyncPattern<> and .FromEvent<>

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were attaching to a standard event? You're getting event args, right?

Comment: If you are refering to a standard event as in its based on sender and event args then yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`Observable.Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244283.aspx)? It should do what you want, or?

```
observable.Subscribe(w => ...).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Catch<>(...);
```

Comment: I can't remember where I read it but I heard that using Timeout is not the best thing to use as it cause's exceptions and other issues.

Answer (score -2):

Try using Latch in C#

http://www.itdevspace.com/2009/05/c-latch-implementation.html

Comment: Did you mean to use for debugging? I can't see how this can be useful.

Comment: This is highly not recommended. Use TPL if you must.